# How can i plug a secong monitor to my pc that only has an hdmi port?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

***My monitor only has vga input/output*** and my pc only has on *hdmi port*, occupied by my main monitor.
My pc is a "Gigabyte Brix GB-BSI3-6100 - Barebone PC" (used for work.)

i found those old monitors in my basement and wondered if i could plug one of em.

Comment: Google "Mini DisplayPort". Does your pc have a port that looks like that? If so you could use a (male) Mini DisplayPort to (female?) VGA adapter (3 euros over here in NL) https://media.s-bol.com/z72WYXy5wzMY/1200x872.jpg

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xdSLAm9.png

Comment: @Gantendo Some have male VGA and some have female VGA. The female VGA adapters go directly into the monitor while the male adapters need an additional cable. Here are some adapters on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mini+displayport+to+vga

Comment: You could also use USB to VGA but you have no reason to do so with that nifty display port sitting right there.